# How to expose my app outside cluster or vpc my internal load balancer in pprivate EKS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

I am having doubt with AWS EKS

i have EKS cluster (Private subnets) managed worker nodes( private subnets)
and i deployed nginx deplyoment with three replicas and did service internal loadbalancer
i can do curl

getting expected output
problem: How to expose my app outside cluster or vpc

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can have AWS Application Load Balancer added to your EKS cluster and have an ingress targeting your service.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/alb-ingress.html

- Deploy ALB Controller in your cluster
- Add new ingress pointing your service

Remember to make `alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing` as you want to expose your service to public.

You can get DNS of new ingress in AWS Console(EC2/Load Balancer) or by describing ingress using kubectl.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your EKS nodes in private subnet of VPC but you need public subnets also for exposing your pods/containers.

So ideally you need to create a LB service for your nginx deployment.

The below blog helped me during my initial EKS setup hope it helps you too

[Nginx ingress controller with NLB](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/network-load-balancer-nginx-ingress-controller-eks/)